# Add an Android binary library to an Eclipse project without gradle

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a legacy eclipse Android project. The classic old way without gradle.
Suppose I found a library I want to integrate with, for example 'commons-codec', than quoting from gradle manual https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_dependencies, I need to paste the below in my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2'
        }
    }
```

Now my eclipse project does not use gradle.
**The Question:** Is there a way to get the binary lib & integrate with it in eclipse (something similar to download the library's jar and add it)? I know this question is bizarre since I need the jar to be in the repository, but I want to be sure I'm not overlooking anything.
Many Thanks!

Comment: Download the JAR. Put it in your project's `libs/` directory. Done.

Comment: How do I download the jar, if the publisher of the library assumes (incorrectly in my case) I am using gradle, and instructs integration only by the gradle snippet above?

Comment: Find it on the JCenter or Maven Central Web site, both of which offer ways of downloading the JAR directly from the site.

Comment: Thx a lot CommonsWare! This answers my question :).Thanks for "connecting the dots" for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using a jar, you can include it in the libs folder of the Eclipse project.  But that's code only.  If there's resources in the library, you'd need to build an Android Library project out of it and include that in your project.  Which I'm not sure how you'd do without code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having **.jar** file the simply right click on your project then

```
Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries-->Add Jar/ Add External Jar--> Apply
```

And if you are having library in your workspace then

```
 Properties-->Android-->Add-->locate your library-->Apply
```